# How to make session.upload_progress work with PHP 5.4 + nginx

Tags: php, file-upload, nginx, progress

I had written a PHP form to upload file like this

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="123" />   
<input type="file" name="file1" />   
<input type="file" name="file2" />   
<input type="submit" />    
</form>
```

(from here:http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php)

Now I want to grab my upload progress by ajax(get) so I create an iframe and make my form target to this iframe
Then, i create another php file to get status...

```
<? php
$key=ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix")."FORM NAME";
$_SESSION[$key]...
```

...well.. $_SESSION is null on nginx-1.4.1 but this method work on my apache
(i use the same script for each server)
Here is the php.ini for session.upload_progress

session.upload_progress.cleanup On

session.upload_progress.enabled On

session.upload_progress.freq    1%

session.upload_progress.min_freq    1

session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS

session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_

how to fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx buffers the request body (including file uploads), so PHP sees the file only when the browser has finished sending it, making the feature useless.

Unfortunately it's not currently possible to disable request body buffering in nginx. Some people have created [nginx patches](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fastcgi_request_buffering%22%20nginx).

An alternative could be to use this nginx module: [HttpUploadProgressModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule